# Opening Linux Subsystem (Bash on Ubuntu on Windows) at a certain directory

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

Are there any arguments available so the bash doesn't start in the home dir, but another one?

Thank you

Comment: You can set any directory you want by adding a `cd` command to the end of `$HOME/.bashrc`. You can also set additional environment variables, add new directories to `PATH`, create new functions, etc.

Comment: I want to make a shortcut depending on the project. If I'm working on 5 projects, I need 5 shortcuts. So I don't think @AFH 's solution will work.

Comment: For @Biswa 's suggestion, there is no "Shortcut path" setting. "Start in" doesn't work because it expects a windows path. I was hoping to be able to add it in target somehow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- First install Windows Subsystem Linux in your Windows PC. Go to the folder `C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs` in other words put this `%AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs` in file explorer. You can find a shortcut named "Bash on Ubuntu on Windows".

[image: Bash shortcut path]

- Copy the shortcut in any other folder. Right click on that shortcut and open *shortcut tab* in *properties*. 
  See the default target path is `C:\Windows\System32\bash.exe ~`.  The tilde (the wavy horizontal line character) is used to represent [users' home directories](http://www.linfo.org/home_directory.html). Thus, a user could also return to its home directory by using the tilde as an argument to cd, i.e.,  `cd ~`

[image: Default path in Bash Shortcut]

- *Remove the tilde* (~) from the *target path* and put the folder name in *Start in* option. As example I put "C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell".  Place the folder path in double quote if path has space in it. Now you are ready to launch bash in that folder.

[image: New Bash Start path]

[image: Bash opened in new directory]

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thank you very much.

Comment: Removing the ~ was the missing clue for me. Thanks!

Comment: can not find the "Bash on Ubuntu on Windows" in first pic

Comment: @lsr729 This question was three years old. So it was corect then but not now.

Answer (score 2):

To launch bash at a certain directory edit the .bashrc file.
type `nano .bashrc` to open the file in nano editor. Add the following command:

```
cd <PATH>
```

Where PATH is the path to your directory.
you can even specify a directory on your windows file system:

```
cd /mnt/c/path/in/windows
```

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on my comment, with the additional information in your response, you can achieve what you want by having separate short-cuts with different custom initialisation files in the `bash` run string:-

```
%SystemRoot%\System32\bash.exe --initfile ~/projN
```

Here `N` refers to the different project numbers or names.

Each `~/projN` file should contain:-

```
# Perform normal start-up tasks

[ -r /etc/bash.bashrc ] && . /etc/bash.bashrc
[ -r ~/.bashrc ] && . ~/.bashrc

# Perform additional tasks

cd projNdirectory/
```

Normally a specific initialisation file completely supersedes the normal start-up files, so these need to be invoked in the custom file in order that `bash` will be launched with your familiar environment (prompt, `PATH`, aliases, etc). This is based on the bash documentation:-

```
--init-file file
--rcfile file
       Execute commands from file instead of the system wide initialization
       file /etc/bash.bashrc and the standard personal initialization
       file ~/.bashrc if the shell is interactive (see INVOCATION below).
```